# How to render a Object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a ***Object*** .

My Object is:

```
const ObjectTest = {
        1: {
            id : 1,
            name:'ABC'
        },
        3: {
            id: 3,
            name:'DEF'
        }
}
```

I want it to render as:

```
id is 1 ; name is ABC
id is 3 ; name is DEF
```

I want to make this object in a ***function*** and is called in ***render*** function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Data is an object so directly we can't use map on that, so use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the array first, then use `map` on that to create ui items.

Using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
_renderObject(){
    return Object.keys(ObjectTest).map((obj, i) => {
        return (
            <div>
                id is: {ObjectTest[obj].id} ;
                name is: {ObjectTest[obj].name}
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const ObjectTest = {
    1: {
        id : 1,
        name:'ABC'
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name:'DEF'
    }
}

class App extends React.Component{

    _renderObject(){
        return Object.entries(ObjectTest).map(([key, value], i) => {
            return (
                <div key={key}>
                    id is: {value.id} ;
                    name is: {value.name}
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this._renderObject()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Check this answer also: [Loop an object in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606360/how-to-loop-an-object-in-reactjs)

Comment: You've been missing in ( in your Object.keys example in the map function. Correct:

`code:  return Object.keys(ObjectTest).map( ( obj, i) => { `

Answer (score 13):

all these mappings... Bruh. Use "pre" tag with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
<pre>
  {JSON.stringify(yourdataobject, null, 2)}
</pre>
```

The `pre` tag stands for preformatted text. It just means that whatever is inside is displayed as fixed width and preserves line breaks and whitespace (as written in the HTML code).

JSON.stringify does exactly what it sounds like - turns the object passed in the first argument into a JSON string. The 2nd argument is a replacer function that's not relevant here. The 3rd argument is how much indentation to use - in this case, 2 spaces (which will be be preserved due to the `pre` tag).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

```js
const ObjectTest = {
        1: {
            id : 1,
            name:'ABC'
        },
        3: {
            id: 3,
            name:'DEF'
        }
}
render(){
   return (
         <div>
            Object.keys(ObjectTest).map( (key)=> {
              return <div>
                 <span>"Id is:"{key}<span>
                 <span>"Name is:"{ObjectTest[key].name}<span>
              </div>
            })
         </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In react you can render your wish answer in browser screen by below code

```
import React from 'react';


const ObjectTest = {
  1: {
      id : 1,
      name:'ABC'
  },
  3: {
      id: 3,
      name:'DEF'
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
         {
            Object.keys(ObjectTest).map((value,index)=>{
               <p>id is {ObjectTest[value].id} ; name is {ObjectTest[value].name}</p>
            });
         }
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why it seems that almost every one is using Object.keys!

```js
Object.values(ObjectTest).map((row_, index) =>
    <tr>
    {Object.values(row_).map(item => <td>{item}</td>)}
    </tr>
)}
```

Sample Data:

```html
const ObjectTest = {
        1: {
            id : 1,
            name:'ABC'
        },
        3: {
            id: 3,
            name:'DEF'
        }
}
```