# Loop an object in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Data :

[image]

I have data that have inside arrays, I try loop by default code:

```
 <div className="loop-container">
    {
        joblist.map((itemb,index) => (
            <div>
            </div>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

I want show name of that arrays first, (this is date) then show what this arrays consist, But I get error:

> joblist.map is not a function

Comment: Is `joblist` the **object** that you're showing in your screenshot?

Comment: To be fair the console has your answer. As you can clearly see the `joblist` is an object where the keys are dates and not an array.

Comment: So as @GillesC already said: it's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: `joblist` is not an array, that's an object. You need to convert it to array first.

Comment: I modify to this, now I see all keys `{Object.keys(joblist).map((key) => (
                        <div>{key}</div>

                    ))}` but how next show arrays?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко which value of array object you want to print?

Comment: @MayankShukla created_time for example, it can consist 2 or 3 arrays [2017-08-10] { [array1.created_time],[array2.created_time] need loop all arayys that in that object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Directly we can't use `map`, `filter` on object, first we need to get an array (either property or property values) from that object then only we can.

---

Data that you are getting is not an array, so directly we can't use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). What you need to do is first use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys in an array. Once you get the array use `map` on that and inside `map` function body use another `map` to iterate the values.

You can also use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), but pattern will be not same as [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Write it like this:

```
<div className="loop-container">
    {
        Object.entries(joblist).map(([key, value]) => (
            <div id={key}>
                Date: {key}
                {
                    value.map(el => <div key={el.id}> {el.created_time} </div> )
                }
            </div>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Check this Snippet Using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let obj = {
   'key1': [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
   'key2': [{a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}],
   'key3': [{a:7}, {a:8}, {a:9}]
};

Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {

   console.log('key name = ', key);

   value.map(el => {
      console.log(el.a);
   })
})
```

Check this Snippet Using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
let obj = {
   'key1': [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
   'key2': [{a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}],
   'key3': [{a:7}, {a:8}, {a:9}]
};

Object.keys(obj).map(key => {

   console.log('key name = ', key);

   obj[key].map(el => {
      console.log(el.a);
   })
})
```

Check this Snippet Using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
let obj = {
   'key1': [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
   'key2': [{a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}],
   'key3': [{a:7}, {a:8}, {a:9}]
};

Object.values(obj).map(value => {

   console.log('value = ', JSON.stringify(value));
   
   value.map(el => {
      console.log(el.a);
   })
})
```

Comment: id is not defined, thinks need add id

Comment: oh sorry it should be `key={el.id}` not `{id}`, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you see `joblist` is not array, it is object. If you really want to use `map` then you can use `new Map()`. The [new Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor accepts an iterable of entries. With `Object.entries`, you can easily convert from Object to Map:

```
var mapjoblist = new Map(Object.entries(joblist));

<div className="loop-container">
    {mapjoblist.map((itemb,index) => (
       <div>
        .......

       </div>

     ))}
</div>
```