# How do in map object in rendering a reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I show the following reducer (`myData`) in the component:

```
const initialState = [          // <= STATE AS ARRAY
  {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Name One',
    number: 11
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Name Two',
    number: 22
  }
];

const initialStateNew = {   // <= STATE AS OBJECT
 1: {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Name One',
    number: 11
  },
 2: {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Name Two',
    number: 22
  }
}

export default function myData (state = initialStateNew, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "somthing":
      return {
        ...state
      }
    default:
      return state
   }
}
```

I've combinedReducers this one and called it as `myData` and used `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to map the reducer in the component.

Now the following code works for when using `initialState` :

```
const renData = this.props.myData.map((data, idx) => {
  return (
    <View key={idx}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("ID:  ", data.id)}
      >
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data.id} - {data.name} - {data.number}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
   )
});
```

The code works cause it's an array. How do I map the object `initialStateNew` in `renData`?

---

**Edit1**

this.props.newData is coming from `mapStateToProps`

```
const createUI = () => {
  let uiItems = [];

  for(let i in this.props.newData)
    uiItems.push(<Text key={data[i].id}> {data[i].name} </Text>)

  return uiItems;
}
```

Using in the `View` : `{createUI}`. Getting error:

[image]

---

**Edit2**

```
const createUI = () => {
  let uiItems = [];

  for(let i in this.props.newData)
    uiItems.push(
        <Text key={this.props.newData[i].id}> 
            {this.props.newData[i].name} 
        </Text>
        )
  return uiItems;
}

const renData = this.createUI.map((data, idx) => {
  return (
    <View key={idx}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("ID:  ", data.id)}
      >
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data.id} - {data.name} - {data.number}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
  )
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop on Object in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606360/loop-on-object-in-reactjs)

Comment: Thanks @MayankShukla. I've read that but it's a little confusing. Could you please tell me if there is another way than `map`. I don;t want to use it unless it's required. I think map is used more for arrays, right?

Comment: yes `map` is for array, that's why first we need to use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` then `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change you `renData` like this

```
const renData = Object.keys(this.props.myData || []).map((key, idx) => {
  let data = this.props.myData[key]
  return (
    <View key={idx}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("ID:  ", data.id)}
      >
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data.id} - {data.name} - {data.number}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
   )
});
```

**Edit:**

`Object.keys(this.props.myData)` returns an array of keys (if `this.props.myData` is an object) or returns an array of indexes (i.e.
 ["0"."1", ...]) if it is an array.

`this.props.myData || []` means if `this.props.myData` is null or undefines then just use an empty array. This is there so that it does not throw unnecessary errors when `this.props.myData` is null or undefined.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. What did `Object.keys(this.props.myData)` do exactly?

Comment: Why did you add ` || []`? Does that mean if it's an array or empty?

Answer (score 1):

It's a duplicate of [Loop on Object in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606360/loop-on-object-in-reactjs), but OP don't want to use `map` so alternate solution.

Call a function from render method and use `for` loop on object to create the ui items and return the result.

Like this:

_

```
createUI(){

    if(!Object.keys(data).length) return null;

    let uiItems = [];
    for(let i in data)
        uiItems.push(
            <View key={data[i].id}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => Alert.alert("ID:  ", data[i].id)}
                >   
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data[i].id} - {data[i].name} - {data[i].number}</Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> 
        )

    return uiItems;
}

render(){   
    return(
        <div>
            {this._createUI()}
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
const initialStateNew = {  
 1: {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Name One',
    number: 11
  },
 2: {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Name Two',
    number: 22
  }
}

for(let i in initialStateNew)
  console.log('key, value = ', i, initialStateNew[i].name);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I think I'm able to understand the login here. So first create the array from the objects and than render, right? Where is `data` coming from? I tried this and got an error. Updated my question (`Edit1`). Please help.

Comment: are you getting the data from any api? put the check `if(!Object.keys(data).length) return null;` it will work check the updated answer.

Comment: data you need to replace with your data variable, yes first we need to convert into array then map.

Comment: Ok. Not getting data from api. Getting from an object in the reducer. Now after the `_createUI`,I need to map that array and show the data, right? I tried it (`Edit2` in my question) but not getting anything. What am I missing? Please help. Thanks for your time

Comment: no you don't need map after the `_createUI` after that function wil return the ui part directly, use it exactly as a wrote in answer it will work.

Comment: I changed to use the fat arrow or was getting unexpected token error.  `const createUI = () => {` Not getting any error, but nothing is showing on the view either. Cannot console.log as it breaks my app for some reason. Also tried  `{this.createUI}` and  `{createUI}`. Also tried to `uiItems.push` first before the `for` loop for `<View>` and after the for loop for `</View>`. Even that did not help. I'm doing it on `react-native` if that matters. I think I'm close. Just not showing anything now. Please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152893/discussion-between-somename-and-mayank-shukla).