# How to map an array with custom index in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of values in state as

```
constructor {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        staff: {
                pos1: { name:'Ajith'}
                pos2: { name:'Ben'}
              }
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.staff.map((item,index) => {
        console.log(item+" * "+index)
    }
}
```

I got an error `this.state.staff.map is not a function` as the index is not as `0, 1 etc`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Because this.state.staff is not an array !!. It's an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606360/loop-an-object-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to be noted here based on your question,

Staff is not an array so you wont be able use map, in order for you to use map you will need to object.keys.

Also you are missing a comma in the staff value section.

```
       staff:  {
            pos1: { name:'Ajith'},
            pos2: { name:'Ben'}
          }
```

To use map:

```
  Object.keys(staff).map((data) => staff[data].name )

It will return the output as:

["Ajith", "Ben"]
```

Answer (score 0):

cause `staff` is an `Object` not a `Array`, so you can't map `staff`. But you can try this

`Object.key(this.state.staff).map((key, index) => {
   const item = this.state.staff[key]
   console.log(item+" * "+index)
})`