# Render from object values - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this response object from an api, and I want to loop it and render it as if it was a normal array, how can I render tshirt, jeans and furniture? **I will not like to render the value of sneakers,** Any suggestion?

```
const items = {
        tshirt: "Model TS",
        jeans: "ModelXW",
        sneakers: "indcdsc54",
        furniture: "Table31S"
    };

{Object.keys(items).map=>{i => 
  <Card>
 {items[key]}
  </Card>
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a Object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100477/how-to-render-a-object-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one implementation line:

```
{Object.entries(items).filter(v => v[0] !== 'sneakers').map((v, idx) => <Card key={idx}>v[1]</Card>)}
```

Comment: Can I chain multiple .filter()? Just in case I do not want to render other value?

Comment: Yep! Try adding a const somewhere outside the render with the values you want to exclude, like: `const toExclude = ['sneakers', 'jeans']` and then modify your filter like: `filter(v => !toExclude.includes(v[0]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can read properties of an object using dynamic key: `objectName[keyName]`:

```
{
  Object.keys(items).map(key => <Card key={key}>{items[key]}</Card>)
}
```

and to filter out `sneakers`:

```
{Object.keys(items).filter(key => key !== 'sneakers').map((key) => (
  <Card key={key}>{items[key]}</Card>
))}
```

Comment: This will render all the values, I do not want to render the value of sneakers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple loops, add an `if` condition to your code:

```
Object.keys(items).map(key => {
  if (key != 'sneakers') {
    return(<Card>{items[key]}</Card>);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `destructuring` and it is definitely more readable.

```
  const { sneakers, ...rest } = items;
    
    Object.keys(rest).map((item, id) => {
      <Card key={id}>
          {item}
      </Card>
    }
    );
```

Comment: I recommend the destructuring feature in ES6 for this.