# How can I display this object in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have response from the sarver like this :

```
{
  "response_code": 200,
  "tickets": {
      "3": {
          "117": "http://....../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"
      },
      "4": {
          "118": "http://...../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"
      },
      "5": {
          "119": "http://...../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"
      },
      "6": {
          "120": "http://.../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"
      },
      "7": {
          "121": ""
      },
      "8": {
          "122": "http://..../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

and I should display these links in the websites as it should be an array, but it's an array
so any clue how can I display these links in react app, or how can I convert it to array, so I can display it easily?

Comment: `map` over `Object.values(data.tickets)`. `Object.values` gives you the array of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a Object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100477/how-to-render-a-object-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert the `tickets` object to an array of URLs (ignoring any of those number keys), you can do so using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const obj = {"response_code":200,"tickets":{"3":{"117":"http://....../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"},"4":{"118":"http://...../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"},"5":{"119":"http://...../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"},"6":{"120":"http://.../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"},"7":{"121":""},"8":{"122":"http://..../upload/iblock/4a5/4a529553152b21109e9aa18fa9d4ea9b.pdf"}}}

const tickets = Object.values(obj.tickets).flatMap(Object.values)

console.log(tickets)
```